# What does "connection matched" in PostgreSQL logs mean?

Tags: postgresql

I have this in the logs of a postgres instance:

```
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 06:20:02.277 UTC [78602] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 06:20:02.277 UTC [78602] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 06:41:05.211 UTC [79412] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 06:41:05.211 UTC [79412] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 06:41:45.448 UTC [79517] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-20 06:41:45.448 UTC [79517] DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 07:01:53.432 UTC [80321] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 07:01:53.432 UTC [80321] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 07:22:44.231 UTC [81197] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 07:22:44.231 UTC [81197] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 07:25:30.380 UTC [81317] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-20 07:25:30.380 UTC [81317] DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 07:43:48.611 UTC [82115] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 07:43:48.611 UTC [82115] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 07:47:12.673 UTC [82233] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-20 07:47:12.673 UTC [82233] DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 08:04:33.369 UTC [82925] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 08:04:33.369 UTC [82925] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 08:09:09.023 UTC [83149] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-20 08:09:09.023 UTC [83149] DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 08:25:46.146 UTC [83736] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-20 08:25:46.146 UTC [83736] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2021-11-20 08:30:54.629 UTC [83963] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgadmin"
2021-11-20 08:30:54.629 UTC [83963] DETAIL:  Role "pgadmin" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

This instance is used for tests and contains data of no value, so it is not secured and has a public open port for ease of testing.

What I find odd, if this is an attack, is that the timestamps are spaced a lot:
6:20, 6:41, 7:01, 7:22, 7:25, 7:43, etc I would expect tons of requests in a short period of time, but there is a lot of gap between the connections

What does the "connection matched" message mean?

Comment: If I have two lists, one of open ports and one of common passwords, why would I hammer one port with every password, rather than every port with one password?  The first one seem more likely to get me detected/reported, and offers no advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell you who tries to log in, but you could add `%h` to `log_line_prefix` to see the client address.

“Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100” means that the incoming connection matched that `pg_hba.conf` line (which is no surprise, since it contains all wildcards), and as a consequence, `scram-sha-256` password authentication was attempted (and failed).

I recommend using less generic `pg_hba.conf` entries, so that attackers have less chance to intrude with a guessed password.